# When I click a button, how can I make a word appear in the textbook?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dynamic, textbox

I'm using Visual Studio (C# and designer). I have a button that says "begin" and a text box beside it. When I click "begin" I to make the word "start" to appear in my text box. How do I do that?

Edit: The button is just a text (not a button) and it is in the filter section, and the textbox is in another section, in all different files. If I did this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UL_Ahv-XaMQ, which file would I put it in?

Thank you!

Comment: Go to google, on the search bar type c# winform button click change textbox. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UL_Ahv-XaMQ but please next time do some googling before you ask such questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click on the "begin" button in designer, it will open up the click event of "begin" button, there simply write

```
TextBox1.Text = "Start"
```

You just have to change the text of Text Box on Button click event. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Double click the Button in the designer and you will be taken to the code for the `onClick` event (Visual studio has just created this for you). 
Inside the event braces add the code-

```
Textbox1.Text = "begin";
```

where `'Textbox1'` is the name you have given your textbox.